# How to center align views in Android layout

Tags: android

I am trying to build the following layout on Android: 
[image: layout]

As indicated by the dotted lines:
- The two `TextView`s should be left aligned.
- The `ImageView` should be center aligned with the title `TextView`

The labels should be anchored relative to the parent and each other as indicated in the sketch.

I have tried to implement this using `ConstrainedLayout` which gets me pretty far. But the tricky part is the alignment of image and title.

I would need an attribute like `layout_constraintCenter_toCenterOf` which unfortunately does not exist.

**EDIT: ### removed hard-coded height ###**

There was an unwanted hardcoded height in my code (marked in example below). After removing that it works fine for me.
But the question stands: What is the 'right' way to center-align views?
My solution feels like a hack.

**#######################################**

This is what I got so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="5dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/titleText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"

        ### edit: this line must go:
        ###  android:layout_height="19dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="158dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:text="title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/titleText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:text="subtitle" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried to work around by aligning top and bottom which looks right in the preview but causes glitches in the real app:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image1"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image1"
```

Maybe `ConstrainedLayout` is the wrong tool for the job altogether.

What is the 'right way' to implement this layout in Android?

Comment: It turns out my approach works after all. I just realized that a fixed height for the title has sneaked into my code: `layout_height="19dp"`. If I remove that, the alignment works. It still feels like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/connected_icon_png" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="Title Label"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="Content that you want" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You may able to do further edit if you need.

Happy Coading

Snapshot: [image: Screenshot]

Comment: It does not get me the horizontal center alignment.

Answer (score 0):

## use your widgets inside relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:padding="5dp">


<ImageView
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:src="@color/colorAccent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/titleText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="19dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="abcjdnadnaadjdndd"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:maxLines="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:text="title" />

<TextView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_below="@id/titleText"
    android:id="@+id/detailText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="sadhbhaeadhbaedn"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/titleText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleText"
    tools:text="subtitle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```